# How to put search result of a query in variables in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I want to search some input in a data table and if exact data is found then I want to put those data into another table. If not, I will simply clear the corresponding TextBox. I have done theses so far.

```
    private void btn_InputConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string strConnection = @"Data Source=F_NOOB-PC\;Initial Catalog=ComShopDB;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection objcon = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
    try {
        string strcmd1 = "SELECT partID,partAvailable FROM Parts WHERE partID LIKE '" + txtbox_ProductSerial.Text + "'AND partAvailable ='yes'";
        SqlCommand objcmd1 = new SqlCommand(strcmd1, objcon);
        objcon.Open();
        objcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        objcon.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Some help will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to use `DataAdapter` and then use its `Fill()` function on a `DataTable` or `DataSet`. You do not need to open and close the connection as the `Fill()` function will do that for you:

```
private void btn_InputConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  string strConnection = @"Data Source=F_NOOB-PC\;Initial Catalog=ComShopDB;Integrated Security=True";
  SqlConnection objcon = new SqlConnection (strConnection);

  try
  {
      //Writing command//
      string strcmd1 = "SELECT partID,partAvailable FROM Parts WHERE partID LIKE '" + txtbox_ProductSerial.Text + "'AND partAvailable ='yes'";
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strcmd1, objcon);
      System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
      aa.Fill(ds);
  }
  catch ( Exception ex )
  {
    MessageBox.Show (ex.Message);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `DataTable`, use `ExecuteReader` method and load all records into `DataTable`, then use `AsEnumerable` and some `LINQ` you can get your results as a `List`.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
var reader = objcmd1.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.HasRows)
{
    dt.Load(reader);
    var myValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .Select(d => new { 
                                 Id = d["partID"], 
                                 Available = d["partAvailable"]
                               }).ToList();
}
```

Also you should consider using [`parameterized queries`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) instead to prevent [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) Attacks.

Comment: I wish I could +2 for mentioning the SQL Injection Attack.